# for-loop isn't picking up the if-else statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, web-scraping

I'm struggling to print out 10 rows/outputs in this function. So far, I've two outputs only. Either the for-loop isn't reading line by line by tag, or the if-else statement is buggy.

```
# copy and paste the url from indeed using your search term
URL = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+%2485%2C000&l=New+York'

#conducting a request of the stated URL above:
page = requests.get(URL)

#specifying a desired format of “page” using the html parser - this allows python to read the various components of the page, rather than treating it as one long string.

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#printing soup in a more structured tree format that makes for easier reading
print(soup.prettify())


def extract_salary_from_result(soup): 
  salaries = []
  for td in soup.find_all(name='td', attrs={'class':'snip'}):
    for div in td.find_all(name='div', attrs={'class':'salarySnippet'}):
       salary = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'salary no-wrap'})
       #print('salary in 2nd for-loop', salary)
       #if len(salary) > 0:
       for c in salary:
          salaries.append(c.text.strip())
          print('salary in if statement',salaries)
       else:
          salaries.append('Nothing_found')
          print('salary in else statement',salaries)
  return(salaries)
salary = extract_salary_from_result(soup)
print('salary is: ', salary)
```

**Currently outputs are:**

```
salary in if statement ['$115,000 a year']
salary in else statement ['$115,000 a year', 'Nothing_found']
salary is:  ['$115,000 a year', 'Nothing_found']
```

**the ideal output should be:**

```
['$115,000 a year', 'Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found','Nothing_found']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `if-else` there. You have a `for-else`. You probably want this:

```
   for c in salary:
       if len(c) > 0:
           salaries.append(c.text.strip())
           print('salary in if statement',salaries)
       else:
           salaries.append('Nothing_found')
           print('salary in else statement',salaries)
```

The `else` in `for-else` doesn't take the place of `else` in `if-else`. It's more like a "`finally`" statement (it executes after the loop ends if no `break` statement was encountered).